# Active Reports 2 Install Issue on Win 10

Tags: activereports

We are trying to install Active Reports 2 on a Windows 10 system for a legacy report.  We are getting this error. We tried installing .Net 2 SP2 and get the same error. Have you seen this error before? Also I was not able to locate an installer for MS Help 2.x run time if anyone knows where that might be.

Thanks

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

if you have vs 2003/2005 installed, the Ms help 2.x runtime should be installed.  Make sure you run the installer as admin (right click, Run as Administrator), otherwise it will fail at multiple steps.

Comment: These installs are for our end users. We can't install VS on their machines.

Comment: In that case you are using the wrong msi.  the one that DataDynamics provided is for developers with VS installed.  It is not meant for end users.  

Why would you have your end users install this msi?  it should be a custom install that you create with your application developed using ActiveReports and other stuff in it.  And in that case, you should be using the h2reg that is in teh ActiveReports for .net2.0 msi for ActioveReports documentation.

Comment: edite: from previous comment:
And in that case, you should NOT be using the h2reg that is part of the ActiveReports for .net2.0 msi for ActiveReports documentation